# Cannot get property descriptor of a class property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I want to inspect an instance of a JavaScript class and access its getter. In ES5, I can write this code to [retrieve the getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__lookupGetter__) of an object:

```
var obj = {
  get foo () {}
};

const foo = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor (obj, 'foo').get;
// returns a function
```

However, when I try this on a class instance, my code fails:

```
class Foo {
  get foo () {}
}

var obj = new Foo ();
const foo = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor (obj, 'foo').get;
// error: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` does not seem to work: it returns `undefined`
for the `foo` property.

I am using Babel 6.4.5 to transpile my code from ES2015 to ES5.

Is `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` supposed to work on classes too? Or is this a side effect of using Babel?

---

**EDIT** I've finally switched to `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` as suggested
by Bergi. I describe the solution in detail in a [blog post](http://code.fitness/post/2016/01/javascript-enumerate-methods.html)
([Enumerating methods on a JavaScript class instance](http://code.fitness/post/2016/01/javascript-enumerate-methods.html)).

Comment: The examples are completely different. Your first example creates an object that has a `foo` getter, the second one creates an object that has a prototype which has a `foo` getter.

Comment: Ah, yes. I have ovelooked that! I've still to get my mind around how ES6 classes get mapped to ES5.

Comment: *"I've still to get my mind around how ES6 classes get mapped to ES5"* `class Foo { constructor() { /*constructor*/ } method() {} }`, is (almost) the same as `function Foo() { /*constructor*/ } Foo.prototype.method = function() {};`, except that methods are not enumerable.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It does work with classes, but the *instance* you tried it on has no *own*  property. Use

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), 'foo')
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo.prototype, 'foo')
```

Comment: Thank you. How could I define an _own_ property on a class instance?

Comment: With Babel, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), 'foo').get.name` is equal to `get` and not to `foo`...

Comment: Use `this.foo = …` inside the constructor. Or `Object.defineProperty` for setters/getters.

Comment: @PierreArnaud: I don't think babel guarantees correctly named functions. And according to the spec, it should be `get foo` anyway, which is hardly possible in ES5.

Comment: @Bergi THX a lot. I pulled my hairs out, over this issue; because TypeScript is behaving in the same way (obviously...)

Comment: @ChristianUlbrich typescript compiles it down to a javascript class, so its not typescripts fault.